# How to initialize a variable to an aggregate sum in R

Tags: r, sum, initialization, aggregate

I just started fooling around with R yesterday.  I would like to know how to initialize a variable so that it just prints out the number that was the aggregate sum and not the entire standard aggregate table.  See code below, the result and then the result I want.

```
x = aggregate(SalesAmount ~ ProductCategory, data=subset(df_adventureworks, 
ProductCategory == "Clothing"), FUN=sum)
x
```

Result is:

```
   ProductCategory    SalesAmount
1         Clothing       339772.6
```

I just want the result to print:

```
[1] 339772.6
```

Comment: `x$SalesAmount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sum(df_adventureworks$SalesAmount[df_adventureworks$ProductCategory=="Clothing"], na.rm=T)
```

The `na.rm=T` in the end is in case you have missing values in the data. If not, you can skip it.

Comment: thanks this worked, do you know any good resources that I can leverage to look up this stuff so I can check there first and try (and most likely fail first) before I post to Stackoverflow.  also when you say include 'na.rm=T in the end you mean with out the ' right?  like this after or new line?                                                                                             `y = sum(df_adventureworks$SalesAmount[df_adventureworks$ProductCategory=="Clothing"])`
`na.rm=T`
`y`

Comment: @BrianWiley I edited the code with the `na.rm=T` in the right place. You can pass that argument in a bunch of functions, e.g. min, max, mean etc. For resources, I remember using the R cookbook when first starting, I think you can find a copy of it for free online. That's probably kind of outdated at this point, but it will work with the basics. Also, any primer on `data.tables` and `ggplot2` could be helpful.